# Water mark for Data Grid View in Windows Form using vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, watermark

[image: Water mark for Data Grid View]

I would like to add image as water mark in Data Grid View as shown in attached image.

There is no Data Grid View property for background image to set picture and then set its opacity. I looked for third party to give ability of water mark I found telerik was providing but that is not free.

I need free third party tool for Data Grid View water mark or a way to add watermark myself with out using any tool.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to show the image only while the are no rows?

Comment: I wanted to show image in both case while there is row or not but I have solved my problem I will add answer thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog - 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2008/01/02/datagridview-watermark-cell.aspx

If you just want the watermark in an empty cell as the watermark in DataGridView control, then you can paint the content when you draw the cell, the  article  listed above just said how to customize a watermark column and cell for your DataGridView.

http://www.vb-tips.com/TextAndImageColumn.aspx

Comment: I have gone through this before but it was not beneficial for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlay the cells with an image the readability will suffer greatly.

But you can add an `Image` in a nested `Panel` and **either** hide and show it when the first row is added or the last one removed.

**Or** you could always show it but **move** it under the last row..

The code for this is simple; the nested `Panel` however will move out of the `DataGridView` when to many rows are added.. This example asumes all rows have the same Height.

Set up the nesting:

```
panel1.Parent = dataGridView1;
panel1.Location = new Point(1, dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + 1);
```

Move the panel when necessary:

```
void panelMove()
{
    int rh = dataGridView1.RowCount == 0 ? 0 : dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;
    panel1.Location = new Point(1,
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + 1 + dataGridView1.RowCount * rh);
}
```

For example here:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    panelMove()
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    panelMove()
}
```